# Configure gson to serialize Calendar type for wcf web service

Tags: android, wcf, gson

I have an object that contains a Calendar type representing the CreatedOn date.  I have gotten the adapter to display the milliseconds, but I"m not sure how to output the device configured timezone information as well.

WCF expects dates to be in the following format: `"CreatedOn":"\/Date(1305003600000-0500)\/"`

This is what I currently have:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
  .registerTypeAdapter(GregorianCalendar.class, new JsonSerializer<GregorianCalendar>() {

    public JsonElement serialize(GregorianCalendar date, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
      return new JsonPrimitive("/Date(" + date.getTimeInMillis() + ")/");
    }

}).create();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing the following:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
  .registerTypeAdapter(GregorianCalendar.class, new JsonSerializer<GregorianCalendar>() {
    public JsonElement serialize(GregorianCalendar date, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
      return new JsonPrimitive("\\/Date(" + date.getTimeInMillis() + "-0000)\\/");
    }               
}).create();
```

When I add my object to the HttpPost request as json `StringEntity`, I fix the escaped backslashes:

```
String json = gson.toJson(data).replace("\\\\/", "\\/");
```

I would still be interested in a "better" way of accomplishing this, if it exists...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be done without custom Serializer but using a custom setter of the field:

```
private String CreatedOn;

public void setCreateOn(Calendar date) { this.CreatedOn = "\\/Date(" + date.getTimeInMillis() + "-0000)\\/" ; }
```